# How do I wire a transistor to a dpdt relay

Tags: transistors, esp8266, latching-relay

I have TQ2-L2-3v DPDT relay that is getting activated by an ESP8266-12e pin. The problem is the pin doesn’t always output enough current to activate the relay so I want to wire a transistor (2n2222) to it. My question is since the only relays I have thus far connected to the 2N2222 have been non latching with the positive and ground interchangeable The TQ2-L2-3v has a designated + and - so I am not sure which way to wire it up.
I have made two schematics with the two different way I can think of the wiring.
Can someone tell me which way is the correct A or B, or are these two incorrect and what is the correct wiring?
[image]

Comment: With D1 in the polarity you indicate, you're building a transistor blower-upper.  You want the diode to be blocking when the transistor isn't conducting; it is there to conduct when the transistor turns _off_ and the coil needs a place for its current to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L2 designates a two coil latching relay, so you would need another transistor and GPIO pin.

The + pin will go to Vcc (it will be more positive when the transistor is conducting), but I'm not sure of your diagram- it appears to be rotated  180° for the markings to be readable, assuming it's the top view.

For future reference, please link to the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/315/4514_fileversion-1855604.pdf) PDF in your question text.

[image]

Comment: So let’s say I had the same set up on the other side. If VCC goes to + then B would be the correct set up, right

Comment: But the diode is backwards.

Comment: So the 1n4148 needs to be turned around to go from - to + in B and it should work.

Comment: YES the diode is backwards, otherwise B is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much